# Attempting to access domain login.lotusdocs.com sometimes results in successful access, while at other times, an error message appears

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

Attempting to access login.lotusdocs.com sometimes results in successful access, while at other times, an error message appears, stating "SORRY! If you are the owner of this website, please contact your hosting provider: webmaster@login.lotusdocs.com. It is possible you have reached this page because." Interestingly, accessing it via the IP consistently works fine. The question is why I'm experiencing issues when accessing it through login.lotusdocs.com.

**Works fine when access with ip:**
[image]

**Error when access via domain:**
[image]

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - php

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=lotusdocs
      - MYSQL_USER=******
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=******
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1 
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:5.0.2
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
      - PMA_PORT=3306
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
     - mysql

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    tty: true
    links:
     - mysql
  composer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: composer.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html/login.lotusdocs.com
```

**nginx.Dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/login.lotusdocs.com

ADD nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**composer.Dockerfile**

```
FROM composer:2.2.0
```

**php.Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:5.6.28-fpm-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/login.lotusdocs.com

RUN apk --update add \
    freetype-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    imagemagick-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd




RUN echo "date.timezone = 'America/New_York'" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/timezone.ini
```

**default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name login.lotusdocs.com;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/html/login.lotusdocs.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

}
```